# OpenJDK9 build fails

Tags: java, java-9

When building OpenJDK-9 on a CentOS-7 machine, the build fails with

> ```
> [...]/jdk/make/src/classes/build/tools/taglet/ExtLink.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
> import jdk.javadoc.doclet.Taglet;
>                          ^
>   symbol:   class Taglet
>   location: package jdk.javadoc.doclet
> ```

and many similar errors after that. This seems to be jdk-9+168 from 2017-05-04.
The error appears after checking out with hg, running configure with no args and starting make. Nothing fancy going on.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: one plus for the simple fact that you are *trying* to build this on your own...

Comment: I wanted to try out shenandoah, which works OK in JDK-8. The build failed for JDK-9, and so I ended up trying the original version, which also failed. Running your own JDK build allows you to monitor JVM code in Oracle Studios profiler.

Comment: probably better to send a note to the jdk-9-dev mailing list instead of posting here.  This is likely going to be a point-in-time issue.

Comment: @AndyGuibert: Even after looking hard, I am not sure which of the many lists is the appropriate one. Those mentioning _jdk9_ in their name (including _jdk-9-dev_) or starting with _build_ make no mention of the offending `Taglet` class thwarting build attempts. On those lists, everyone seems so happy with jdk-9 that I did not want to disturb.
In years past, it was my understanding (based on hearsay) that is it impossible to build a jdk from sources, but the shenandoah fork of jdk8 gave me new hope and I naively tried the same with jdk-9.

Comment: here is a link to the mailing list signup and archives page -- anyone can sign up and participate: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/jdk9-dev